# Get the user name in the JSP page. principal.username not working

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, jspx

I have a fully working Spring Security. I need to print the user name on the page, the controller is not suitable, because this page is part of a template for other pages.

I've tried a lot of options similar to this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
    xmlns:display="http://displaytag.sf.net" version="2.0"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="true" />
    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        omit-xml-declaration="true" />
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    <sec:authentication property="principal.username"></sec:authentication>
</sec:authorize>
...
</body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

But the code does not print, no errors too.
I tried to authenticate different users, and place the code on different pages, but it did not help me.
How to fix it?

Comment: It's my fault ... I thought that the dependence of spring-security-web contains everything you need to work with web part Security, but I forgot about the spring-security-taglibs...

Answer (score 4):

Try this, this is working for me.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<sec:authorize var="loggedIn" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${loggedIn}">
            <%= request.getUserPrincipal().getName() %>        
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: I use jspx, so I can not use something like "<%= request.getUserPrincipal().getName() %>"

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>
```

Comment: Please explain why you answer would work and not just give it,

Comment: did you got this `<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>` in your jsp and got spring security library on your classpath?

Comment: instead of <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %> I use xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" It should be fine, right? Yes, i have spring security lib on my classpath, i used Maven.

Comment: i dont know.. looks like you have different version with me.. sorry